How to implement code into OSL
I want to implement a BSDF into OSL, but I only have a few ideas of how that's done. Do I copy and paste the parameters in the script node?


I've not done any coding in Blender but there seems to be a fairly comprehensive section in the Blender Manual on scripting OSL.
